# How to deny entry in .htaccess and redirect to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using htaccess config for allow only my IP:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from MY.IP
```

How can I redirect on 403 to another domain, for example when 403 -> go to `www.google.com`.

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't send a 403 and redirect (3xx) in the same request. You do one or the other.

To redirect when the requesting IP is not your own then you would need to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_authz... as you are doing. For example, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.0.113.111
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/ [R,L]
```

Where `203.0.113.111` is your IP address and the `https://example.com/` is the URL you want to send all other users to.

However, sending a 403 Forbidden is probably the better response.